# simple way to Change element of parameter

Tags: gams-math

I need to change the element of b (change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 ) to get new parameter c(j). I want to use macro option, is it possible?

```
set j/1*100/;
parameter b(j) ,c(j);
*suppose b(j) initialized
c(j)=b(j);
loop(j,
if(c(j)=1,
    c(j)=0;
else
    c(j)=1;
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in a macro. However, if you just want to toggle 0/1, you can also simply use the `not` operator. Look at this modified version of your code:

```
set j/1*100/;
parameter b(j) ,c(j);
* Fill with random data
b(j) = uniformInt(0,1);
* Note: This is actaully not necessary; you could also use b directly below
c(j)=b(j);

c(j) = not c(j);
```

Comment: I think you could use a macro like: `$macro c(j) (1$(b(j) = 0) + 0$(b(j) = 1));` But it's a bit trivial to use a macro for that because you can just define the parameter c(j) to do the same thing.